# Applied Quick Style in Outlook 2012 has wrong font size

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, fonts, microsoft-outlook-2010

Recently someone asked [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1193661/46099) about emulating the StackOverflow inline code formatting in Microsoft Outlook and I offered up this Quick style:

```
Font: (Default) Consolas, 10 pt, Font color: Black
    Pattern: Clear (Custom Color(RGB(242,242,242))), Style: Linked, Quick Style
    Based on: Normal
```

If I click on the style and start typing then my text comes out as 10pt Consolas in black with a grey background. Which is perfect.

However if I type some text, highlight the bit in the middle of that text that I want to format and then click on the style then all the formatting is applied ***except*** that the font size is set to 11pt. Because it's too big, I have to then manually change the font size to 10pt.

It doesn't matter what the original size of the font was, that formatting always becomes 11pt.

**Given that the style is defined as 10pt, how do I force Outlook to render it at 10pt?**

*I'm running Office Standard 2010 (14.0.7177.5000 32-bit) on Windows 7 Enterprise.*

Comment: Office 2012? Do you mean 2010?

Comment: Sorry about that, you're right, I'll update the question.